# preg_match on dynamic url

Tags: php, preg-match

Is there a way in php to do a preg_match on a url like below

> dynamic/dynamic/dev/new_mobile/lib

and it would only pull out `dev/new_mobile`, and the link also has the ability to be like this too

> dynamic/dynamic/dynamic/tst/new_mobile/lib

In the above example it would only pull out `tst/new_mobile`. The key is it would grab the last two directories before lib. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: what have you tried? let us know if you have a problem with http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: well the thing is dev and new_mobile could also change, and I forgot to mention there could be more directories after lib. The only thing that is constant is before lib there is two directories that I need to grab

Comment: Have you tried using `preg_match`? Because it can handle pretty much anything you could throw at it. Or is your question *"please write my regex for me because I don't know how"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex that will get the part you want:

```
$url = 'dynamic/tst/new_mobile/lib/foo/bar';

if (preg_match('#^(?:.*?/)?([^/]+/[^/]+)/lib(?:/.+)?$#', $url, $matches)) {
    $part = $matches[1];
    var_dump($part); // "tst/new_mobile"
}
```

This will get the 2 directories before the lib directory allowing for any directories before and after. It will also match a couple of edge cases that you don't mention whether you need:

```
tst/new_mobile/lib/foo/bar
/tst/new_mobile/lib/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 2):

just explode then reverse array, simple and easy to use.

```
$array_url = explode('/',$url);

$tmp_array_url = array_reverse($array_url);
```

then you can rebuild as you will, no need to wonder with how many dynamic parts come before.

```
echo $tmp_array_url[0]; // "lib";
echo $tmp_array_url[1]; // "new_mobile";
echo $tmp_array_url[2]; // "dev";
```

EDIT: since you got lib constant, just do something like this :

```
$the_two_before = "";
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_array_url); $i++){
    if($tmp_array_url[$i] == "lib"){
         $the_two_before = $tmp_array_url[$i+2]."/".$tmp_array_url[$i+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: well the thing is dev and new_mobile could also change, and I forgot to mention there could be more directories after lib. The only thing that is constant is before lib there is two directories that I need to grab

Comment: mind to be more accurate on why you need that? might have an option via $_SERVER vars but i'm not sure if appropriated.

Comment: I need it because I save those two variables in a $_SESSION and I have to use it later on in the application to look for a correct file.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I changed .length to count($tmp_array_url); and it worked fine.